# Is there a way to view a list of the flags you have cast

Tags: support, flags

I tried looking at my user page, but I cannot seem to find a "flags" tab. So I was wondering: how can I view a list of all the flags I have cast on a particular SE site? Can I, in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your profile, go to the [activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/269069/mickg?tab=topactivity) tab. At the top, you'll see this:

[image]

The text I've surrounded by the red box is what you should click on to see your list of flags for the site. On your Meta SE account, it will show up empty, as you have not cast any helpful flags.